# Reverse iteraror RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reverse, rdd

I have code on a pure Scala of the following kind:

```
import breeze.numerics.log
import spire.random.Dist
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer


def foo1(zs: Buffer[Double])={
  val S = zs.zip(zs.reverse)
    .map { case (x, y) =>log(x) * log(1 - y) }.sum
  S
}

val x = Dist.uniform(0.0, 1.0).sample[Buffer](10)
val y = x.sortWith(_<_)
val cdf=new NormalDistribution(0, 1)
val z = y.map(x_ => cdf.cumulativeProbability(x_))

foo1(z)
```

`z` is sorted because the `cdf` is increasing

I want to rewrite it for Spark, but for the RDD data type there's no reverse method. How do I write this code for Spark?

```
def foo2(z_rdd: RDD[Double])={
    var S = z_rdd.zip(z_rdd.???)
    .map { case (x, y) =>log(x) * log(1 - y) }.sum
    S
}
```

where `???`function that is reversed `z_rdd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to zip RDD with the reversed copy of itself, you should keep in mind that Spark zip requires both RDDs to be equally partitioned:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zip-org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD-scala.reflect.ClassTag-

> Assumes that the two RDDs have the *same number of partitions* and the *same number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through a map on the other).

Therefore, the way to accomplish `rdd zip rdd.reversed` is to:

1. Apply `zipWithIndex` to the RDD, as already suggested
2. Sort it in the reversed order and zip resulting RDD with index as well
3. `reduceByKey` or `groupByKey` the union of the RDDs from step 1 and 2 , with index as the key

I'm not sure if this recipe could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can add indexes to values of your RDD using `zipWithIndex`, and then sort by the index in reverse:

```
z_rdd.zip(
  z_rdd.zipWithIndex()
    .sortBy(_._2, ascending = false)
).map({ case (doubleA, (doubleB, _)) =>
  …
})
```